# pie chart best api for android

Tags: android, charts

I'm developing an android app and I need do implement a pie chart. I've searching for some alternatives but the APIs that I've found are a little limited in terms of animations and graph customization.

Does anyone knows the best way to implement a pie chart that can rotate when touched?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[I like Charts4j](http://code.google.com/p/charts4j/). You can use it to create a few kinds of pie charts. If you put the resulting drawables into a view you could probably figure out some way to interpret touch events to trigger rotate animation effects.

Comment: Thanks by the tip. The ideia of put drawables into views to trigger animation effects sounds good ;)

Comment: Thanks FoamyGuy, but it looks require internet connection to get it work, does it ?